# grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry:

Tags: server

I'm trying to run sudo apt upgrade but getting the following error:

```
Setting up shim-signed (1.34.9+13-0ubuntu2) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: No such file or directory.
dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 installed shim-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried reinstalling grub but nothing seems to be working, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Open up gparted (if not istalled we can help but it's easy enough) and let us know what is showing in Partition / File System / Mount Point

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this, this is a headless server/vps.  I just installed and ran gparted and got this output:

```~$ sudo gparted
Unit -.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.

(gpartedbin:12000): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:24:05.324: cannot open display:
```

Comment: I should also mention that I just recently upgraded this server from Ubuntu 16 to Ubuntu 18 and had to edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` manually to add bionic main universe multiverse and bionic-security main universe multiverse as sources, could that be affecting this?